# Meaning of multiple exposures in a DAG

Tags: inference, causality, dag, causal-diagram

I am working with DAGs as a way to do some causal modeling. I am using dagitty - both the website and the R package. I feel like I have a good grasp of most things related to confounding, adjustment sets, and so on. However, something has me confused. Let me demonstrate by example.

Assume I have the DAG
[image]

I understand (and dagitty confirms) that to extract a causal value for E1 I need to adjust for C. Dagitty reports "

[image: dagitty adjustment set]

So, for example, if everything was linear, I would build a model O ~ E1 + C, and I would intepret the coefficient of E1 as causal. I understand that I **cannot** interpret C as causal - this would violate the ["Table 2 Fallacy"](https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kws412).

Now for the part that confuses me. Dagitty allows a user to pick **multiple exposures**. So, for example, I can choose both E1 and C as "exposures".

[image]

Dagitty now tells me that "No adjustment is necessary to estimate the total effect of E1,C on O." This would **seem** to suggest that the same model: O ~ E1 + C can be used, but now ?both? E1 and C have casual meaning. Obviously, this is wrong.

My question is - what is the meaning of "the total effect of E1,C"? Since C causes E1 (by my diagram) I can't set them independently. More generally, what is the meaning of **any** multiple exposure selection. In other words, let's say I had the DAG E1 -> O <- E2. What would be the meaning of setting **both** E1 and E2 as exposures?

Thanks in advance for any explanations. Every time I think I have my head wrapped around causal inference, some new "wrinkle" pops up.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the same estimation procedure you used in the first case, *cannot* be used in the second.

**DAG 1**:

In the first case, you rely on a very special case where the average causal effect (ACE) can be estimated. Specifically, if (1) the outcome is continuous, (2) the true model specification has not interaction terms, and (3) a single exposure; then the coefficient for $E1$ can be interpreted as the ACE for $E1$ on $O$. As you say, trying to interpret the coefficient for $C$ leads to the Table 2 Fallacy.

A more general approach (i.e., it works when the outcome is not continuous or when there are interaction terms) is [g-computation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3105284/). Briefly, we would estimate the outcome model as suggested. Then we would manually set $E1 = 1$ in a copy of the data set and use the fitted model to *predict* $O$ for everyone with $E1$. This process would then be repeated for $E1=0$. Then we would take the mean of those predictions under each set $E1$ and then subtract. This gives us the ACE while allowing for more complex models. Furthermore, it prevents the Table 2 Fallacy by only providing the ACE as the output.

**DAG 2**:

Now in the second example, you try to use the linear regression trick but it won't work in this case. There are now *two* exposures that we are setting. Specifically, we may want to estimate the ACE had everyone been given $E1=1,C=1$ versus had everyone been given $E1=0,C=0$. The linear regression coefficients cannot give you these comparisons (since they condition on the other). Trying to interpret these issues again would end up with the Table 2 Fallacy. However, the problem is not in the identification but it is in the estimation approach you are using.

Instead, you can use the g-computation procedure. After estimating the model (as done before), you would now set both $E1$ and $C$ then generate the predicted values. Therefore, the problem is not in identification (daggity is correct in saying the causal effects are identifiable) but is a problem in the estimation strategy (since it is a special case that doesn't apply in the latter).

From a graphical perspective. The $C \rightarrow E1$ in the second DAG doesn't mean much. In our intervention (on both exposures), we are setting both $E1$ and $C$. By setting both, $C$ would no longer be predictive of $E1$ (e.g., we are setting $E1 = 1$ under our intervention and it doesn't depend on the value of $C$).

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed reply. I do have a follow-up. 

In your explanation, you describe (using the g-computation approach) "setting both E1 and C". This (rather than the linear regression part - which turned out to be a distraction) was my main source of confusion. 

If, as posited, C -> E1, then an intervention where we are "setting both E1 and C" seems to violate the causal structure of the system.

Comment: The causal structure of the system in DAG 2 is like what happens out in the world (i.e., observational data). This DAG is distinct from a DAG that represents application of the intervention on the system. Under you intervention, you are setting E1 and C from outside the system, so there would be no input arrows from other variables (for the ACE). DAG 2 tells you whether you can identify the effect of that intervention given the observational data (i.e., it does not represent the intervention itself)